# Center align the contents of cells in QTableView

Tags: qt, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I've a QTableView.

Is there a way to align to the centre, all the cell contents of this view?

I'm not using any delegate. It's just an `AbstractTableModel` which is added as a model to a `QTableView`.

How should I align each cell content to the centre?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't want to use custom delegates, you can set this in `data` function of your model implementation, using `Qt::TextAlignmentRole`:

```
QVariant MyModel::data ( const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole )
{
         if (role == Qt::TextAlignmentRole )
             return Qt::AlignCenter;
         else
             return QAbstractItemModel::data(index, role);
}
```

Comment: `Qt::AlignCenter ` is defined as `Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter `. The second one is not needed.